# Calculating electrodynamic momentum of a dumbbell (consisting of two point charges) in longitudinal motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, momentum, classical-electrodynamics, integration

I'm working through a paper on momentum in electrodynamics that requires the integration below and would greatly appreciate any help. I'm pretty sure it evaluates to $2/d$ but I can't quite figure how.

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\pi}
{r^{4}\sin^{3}\left(\theta\right)
\over
\left\{(r^{2} + d^{2}/4)^2 - \left[rd\cos\left(\theta\right)\right]^{2}\right\}^{3/2}}
\,{\rm d}r\,{\rm d}\theta  \space-[1]
$$

If I focus on the integration w.r.t. r first, I get [2]. If I focus on the integration w.r.t. $\theta$ first, I get [3]. A,B,C are just constants w.r.t. the variable of integration.

I believe I can make a series of substitutions but they don't seem to get me closer to an answer.

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} {Ar^{4}
\over
\left[(r^{2} + B)^2 -\left(rC\right)^{2}\right]^{3/2}}\,{\rm d}r   \space-[2]
$$

$$
\int_{0}^{\pi}
{A\sin^{3}\left(\theta\right)
\over
\left\{(C)^2 - \left[B\cos\left(\theta\right)\right]^{2}\right\}^{3/2}}
\,{\rm \rm d}\theta  \space-[3]
$$

Answer (score 1):

As you mention that the integral is used to calculate e.m. momentum of a dumbbell in longitudinal motion, I can give you a link to a paper dealing with the subject: 
https://www.academia.edu/3214673/Electromagnetic_Interaction_Momentum_and_Simultaneity 
the paper makes a reference to a paper by Griffiths and Owen where the integral is calculated. The integral can be also obtained as products of q and A (vector potential)...

Comment: Thanks. I have been using the paper by Griffiths and Owen. Unfortunately, it doesn't provide any details on how the integral was solved. But based on the result in the paper, I can infer this integral evaluates to 2/d